# What is the rate at which Google CV is learning new words

Tags: computer-vision, google-cloud-vision

I'm working with Google CV and I want to allow users to search for things in a collection of pictures. I really want to eliminate the possibility of a user entering "XYZ" for search where XYZ is a word that isn't available to be recognized in Google CV yet. Like the user will be like, "I can see that there are pictures of XYZ in my collection, but when I search for them using XYZ, why do I see zero pictures?"

So I'm gonna make the search field as a auto-complete field where user is only allowed to search for things that can be recognized by Google.

I'm mostly interested in following two pieces of information -

1. Is there a list that is publicly available which has the terms that Google CV can currently recoganize?
2. What is the rate at which Google CV is learning to recognize new things. Like 100 per day or something?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

You can find the list of terms recoganized by Google CV using the Knowledge Graph(KG) API. See the article:
https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/

I hope that this help you.

Best regards,